# Floating point precision - follow up

Tags: r, floating-point

Can anyone explain the following:

```
> any(seq(from=-10.1,to=10.1,by=0.1)==0)
[1] FALSE

> any(seq(from=-1.1,to=1.1,by=0.1)==0)
[1] TRUE
```

This confuses me a lot. It has probably something to do with floating point precision in R, but I am not able to wrap my head around it.

If you print the sequences, in the first case 0 is represented as `0` and in the second it's `1.776357e-15`. But why is the switch from 1.1 to 10.1 invoking this behaviour. Both numbers are float anyway. right?

Comment: Most likely because the error due to the FP precision on each sum of the first case (i.e. `-10.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 ...`) cumulates differently than the second case, and in the second case luckily the sum leads to zero...

Comment: That's the reason why programmers keep saying that `FP_NUM1 == FP_NUM2` should be avoided. You should do `abs(FP_NUM1-FP_NUM2) < tinynum (e.g. 1e-13)` instead

Comment: @digEmAll thanks for the explanation